# Windows Universal App - Launch CMD from app

Tags: c#, windows, cmd

I'm building my first Win 10 app (in Visual C#) and I had a quick question. (I'm a Java/ Android guy)

I want to be able to run cmd line programs from my app. This will be a desktop app and I need to have the ability to shutdown, restart, lock, and abort a restart from the app. I know I can use the 'Shutdown' cmd, but how can I launch it?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't shutdown Windows from a Universal app.   How can a runtime that supports phones and tablets give you a way to run a windows command line application?  You say you want a desktop app.  If you do then you should write a desktop app using Windows Forms or WPF.  A universal app is not a desktop app.

Comment: @shf301 And good luck finding a command line on an Xbox (another universal platform).

Comment: I know... But I want to use Cortana to connect it to a shutdown command. Cortana is only available in a Universal app.

Comment: I haven't tried that with x86 or x64 Windows, but for ARM device you can do the following: 1) Add the Windows IoT Extensions for the UWP; 2) edit the Package.appxmanifest file in your project and in the Capabilities section add   <iot:Capability Name="systemManagement" />, also in the same file in the package "imports" add  xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10" , latter in your code add the following lines:  ShutdownManager.CancelShutdown();
            ShutdownManager.BeginShutdown(Windows.System.ShutdownKind.Restart, TimeSpan.FromHours(23.5));

Comment: Maybe in the Windows Destop Extensions for UWP there is a Shutdown Manager with the same parametters

Answer (score -3):

Any program you can run from the command line is a program you can run without the command line. For example, `shutdown`; try opening the Run box (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and typing:

```
shutdown /r /t 60
```

You'll see that Windows warns the system will be rebooting in 60 seconds (of course, `shutdown /a` will abort the shutdown). So, you should just be able to use [`Process.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6ak8zt5(v=vs.110).aspx) to run the command. No need to launch a full command line.

Comment: That is exactly my problem. I can't use Process.Start  "The type or namespace Process does not exist..."

Comment: You need `using System.Diagnostics` at the top of your file. `Process` lives in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

Comment: Like Shmuel said, in a Universal Windows Application, `Process` isn't supported in the `System.Diagnostics` class.

Comment: @crclayton Ahh, I didn't see he was making a Windows Universal app. My bad.