# Building DefaultApp for Raspberry PI 2 - Windows 10 IoT

Tags: powershell, win-universal-app, windows-10, .net-core, windows-10-iot-core

if anyone tried to execute powershell command like "shutdown / r / t 0" in universal app with c# code? Someone told me that Default app in Windows 10 IoT, is Universal App written with c# and there is an option to restart and shutdown.

If this is not possible tell me if I am able to restart or turn off raspberry pi 2 in diffrent way with c# code.

Comment: Shutdown.exe is NOT a powershell command.
Powershell commands (CMDlets) have a very clear setup of verb-noun (like Get-Command).

I've done some minor things woth iot on a pi2, not sure if you can iniate a shutdown command in an universal app though...

Comment: But how to initiate any command in C# program  (universal apps) with raspberry pi 2, windows iot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Windows Universal App - Launch CMD from app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883136/windows-universal-app-launch-cmd-from-app)

What you are trying to achieve seems not possible at this moment.